# Akka Stream - Splitting flow into multiple Sources

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a TCP connection in Akka Stream that ends in a Sink. Right now all messages go into one Sink. I want to split the stream into an unknown number of Sinks given some function.

The use case is as follows, from the TCP connection I get en continuous stream of something like `List[DeltaValue]`, now I want to create an actorSink for each `DeltaValue.id` so that i can continuously accumulate and implement behaviour for each `DeltaValue.id`. I find this to be a standard use case in stream processing but I'm not able to find a good example with Akka Stream.

This is what I have right now:

```
def connect(): ActorRef = tcpConnection
    .//SOMEHOW SPLIT HERE and create a ReceiverActor for each message
    .to(Sink.actorRef(system.actorOf(ReceiverActor.props(), ReceiverActor.name), akka.Done))
    .run()
```

Update:
I now have this, not sure what to say about it, it does not feel super stable but it should work:

```
  private def spawnActorOrSendMessage(m: ResponseMessage): Unit = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    system.actorSelection("user/" + m.id.toString).resolveOne().onComplete {
      case Success(actorRef) => actorRef ! m
      case Failure(ex) => (system.actorOf(ReceiverActor.props(), m.id.toString)) ! m
    }
  }

  def connect(): ActorRef = tcpConnection
    .to(Sink.foreachParallel(10)(spawnActorOrSendMessage))
    .run()
```

Comment: Added some more content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should be a somewhat improved version of what was updated in the question. The main improvement is that your actors are kept in a data structure to avoid `actorSelection` resolution for every incoming message.

```
  case class DeltaValue(id: String, value: Double)

  val src: Source[DeltaValue, NotUsed] = ???

  src.runFold(Map[String, ActorRef]()){
    case (actors, elem) if actors.contains(elem.id) ⇒
      actors(elem.id) ! elem.value
      actors
    case (actors, elem) ⇒
      val newActor = system.actorOf(ReceiverActor.props(), ReceiverActor.name)
      newActor ! elem.value
      actors.updated(elem.id, newActor)
  }
```

Keep in mind that, when you integrate Akka Streams with bare actors, you lose backpressure support. This is one of the reasons why you should try and implement your logic within the boundaries of Akka Streams whenever possible. And this is not always possible - e.g. when remoting is needed etc.

In your case, you could consider leveraging `groupBy` and the concept of [substream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Implementing_reduce-by-key). The example below is folding the elements of each substream by summing them, just to give an idea:

```
  src.groupBy(maxSubstreams = Int.MaxValue, f = _.id)
    .fold("" → 0d) {
      case ((id, acc), delta) ⇒ id → delta.value + acc
    }
    .mergeSubstreams
    .runForeach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks nice example, in my case I have no control of the sending TCP socket and it will be of no use if can not consume in the same rate as it produces, so back pressure is not any help for me is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

**EventStream**

You can send messages to the ActorSystem's [`EventStream`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/event-bus.html#Event_Stream) within a stream sink and separately have the Actors subscribe to the stream.

**Split At Stream Level**

You can split the stream at the stream level using [Broadcast](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Broadcast.html).  The [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html) has a good example of this.

**Split At Actor Level**

You could also use [`Sink.actorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/akka/stream/scaladsl/Sink$.html#actorRef[T](ref:akka.actor.ActorRef,onCompleteMessage:Any):akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[T,akka.NotUsed]) in combination with a [`BroadcastPool`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/routing.html#BroadcastPool_and_BroadcastGroup) to broadcast the messages to multiple Actors.

Comment: Both cases require that i know upfront how many actors i need, i have aded some more info the the question about what im trying todo

Comment: @user3139545 Updated with another alternative that allows for unknown number of subscribers...

Comment: I could also just spawn child actors from my sink actor and forward to them, however this seems like something that akka stream has build in support for so that i dont have to handle all the extra when doing this with pure actors. What about the partition function? Sounds perfect but cant find any examples of it